# Latex: \printglossaries not working on Mac?

Tags: latex

I want to implement
a simple glossary. I have the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I use TexPad on Mac. 
The \printglossaries command doesn't work. I don't get errors and it does not print the glossaries. Does someone has an idea why?

This is the .pdf I get: [GlossariesTest.pdf](http://docdro.id/GXvzrgS)

Comment: You could try this on https://tex.stackexchange.com. Make sure to mention in this post what exactly "does not work". Linking to the PDF is ok, but a simple sentence saying what happens and what you expected is much clearer and faster.

Comment: How do you compile your document? What sequence of commands do you issue?

Answer (score 3):

This minimal example works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{latex}{
    name=latex,
    description={is a mark up language specially}
}
\begin{document}
The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language.
\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

Note that I used `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries` instead of `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossaries`. If I read table 1 on page 17 of the [Glossaries Beginner's Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) correctly, you need to run `makeglossaries`, `xindy` or such for the commands you used.

With this input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{latex}{
    name=latex,
    description={is a mark up language specially}
}
\begin{document}
The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I need to run `pdflatex test.tex`, then `makeglossaries test`, and another `pdflatex test.tex` to get the glossary printed.

Comment: @JoeChampions What did you try exactly, what happened, and what did you expect to happen instead? If you want us to help you'll need to be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: \printglossaries does not work. I can't see the glossary in the .pdf file.

Comment: @JoeChampions Works for me. You must be doing something wrong.